# Best way to run commands on a VM without SSH

Tags: virtualization

I want to run commands on a VM and get the output without SSH, since the VM will run some network tests which might bring down the interface and the IP might not be always available. What would be the best way to achieve this through /dev/pts/X ?

I am able to run any command via

```
echo "some command" > /dev/pts/2   (or /dev/pts/4 with virtio)
```

and see it on the VM (using virt-manager) but I don't know how to capture the output, how long to wait until the command has finished execution and its return code... Any hints?

This is an XML extract of my VM:

```
<serial type='pty'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
  <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
    <model name='isa-serial'/>
  </target>
  <alias name='serial0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
  <alias name='serial0'/>
</console>
<console type='pty'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/4'/>
  <target type='virtio' port='1'/>
  <alias name='console1'/>
</console>
<channel type='pty'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/3'/>
  <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='connected'/>
  <alias name='channel0'/>
  <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
</channel>
```

Comment: How about a separate interface for SSH?

Comment: I sometimes need to restart and re-configure the whole network, and when it's down I need to interact to do some configuration. So, no option :)

Comment: Do you want to use `/dev/tty` instead of `/dev/pts`?

Comment: Is there an advantage for using /dev/tty ?

Answer (score 1):

The following method has many drawbacks, may not work properly, IS NOT secure :( Inspired by this article [How To Use Host Serial Port From Guest In VirtualBox](https://techtooltip.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/using-host-serial-port-from-guest-in-virtual-box/).

#### Requirements:

- [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) or any program that can send raw bytes in TCP socket
- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or any hypervisor
- root user password

#### Procedure:

- Install VirtualBox guest additions in the Linux VM. Shut it down.
- Go to that VM settings in VirtualBox → open "Serial Ports" section → Check "Enable Serial Port" in Port 1 → Port Number COM1 → Port Mode TCP → Uncheck "Connect to existing" → set Path/Address any unallocated TCP/IP port number e.g. 1234.

[image: VirtualBox_Serial_Port_Settings]

- Start that VM. Run this command `sudo cat /dev/ttyS0 | sh` in VM. This command opens the serial device in VM, pipes the output to shell to run it.
- In host OS side, open Putty → select RAW mode in connection type → enter `localhost` in host name and previous port number in VM setting e.g. 1234. Or run this command `putty -raw localhost -P 1234`.
- Now type anything in putty window, it will be executed in VM's shell.

The COM port and serial devices can be changed and are mapped according to this [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#serialports).